# What is the age or height at which one needs to pay for BTS?

Tags: public-transport, bangkok, age-limits

I have a daughter who wants to come with me to explore Bangkok, she's seven. I would go by BTS but not sure at what age children need to pay for ticket.

**EDIT:** My daughter is 125cm (49in)

**What is the age or height at which one needs to pay for BTS?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My apologies, the first answer was applicable to MRT (subway) ... She is young enough for free child travel (until age 14), but too tall as 90 cm is the cut off height.

On the brightside, child fares on quite cheap starting at 8 baht.
[Bangkok Expressway And Metro](https://www.bangkokmetro.co.th/ticket.aspx?Menu=60&Lang=En)  (same basic rules for purple line)

For the Sky Train, they offer only Student Rabbit Cards (stored value cards), but normal fares for single tickets.

Comment: The linked site says the 50% fare is from 90 cm to 120 cm and up to 14 yo. So still doesn't qualify for a child fare? (note: my 4 year olds are already too tall. Yikes.)

Comment: @mkennedy - it says "and" not "or", so kids need to meet both conditions.  My 4 year old is also too tall.